# Datatables header misalignment

Tags: jquery, datatables

The picture below shows the header of the datatable misalignment before you click on the textbox (search/filter..). once the latter becomes in focus, the header aligns again. I noticed that when scrollY is off the header is fine, i need it on. any idea how to fix it.
in the following snippets, just change the paging option and you can see the realignment of the header again.

```js
$('#RegSrc').DataTable({
   dom:"<'row'<'#tblnoitfy'>><'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
            select: true,
            scrollY: 200,
            deferRender: true,
            //scrollY:     500,
            responsive: false,
            fixedHeader: {
                header: true,
                footer: true
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            bAutoWidth: true,
            data: [],
            rowCallback: function (row, data) { },
  });

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#mdl").dockmodal();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://uxmine.com/demo/dockmodal/assets/js/jquery.dockmodal.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://uxmine.com/demo/dockmodal/assets/css/jquery.dockmodal.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click ME!" />


<div style="display:none">
  <div id="mdl" class="panel-body">
    <input id="RegSrcsrcctl" type="text" />
    <input id="bt1" type="button" value="dummy search" />
    <table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th><b>File Number</b></th>
          <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
          <th><b>DOB</b></th>
          <th><b>Age</b></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to add some code for us to help you. Ideally some sample html/js replicating the issue.

Comment: I will be adding it now

Comment: I m using a bit different CSS in my project by yet even with the default ones i still get the same header mis-format

Comment: I tried, did not work, still getting the same format problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I noticed that the reason for the misaligned table width is due to the width being explicitly set to `100px` initally, instead of the correctly calculated width. This may not address the issue at hand, but a workaround is to force the `table` and wrapper `div` elements to `width:100%`. Doing this does work for the scenarios I tested on, but be advised it may cause issues with certain responsive behavior. The adjustment is to add the following css:

```
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner{
  width:100% !important;
}
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table{
  width:100% !important;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok I took a look at some similar issues, and its related to the fact that your table is displayed in a modal. The modals full view is only rendered after the datatable is set up, so there can be issues with column sizing until you force an action to redraw it, like changing the window size or selecting one of the datatable options. The solution is to call `columns().adjust()` on the open event of the modal, so the table is redrawn after the modal is displayed. So I went a took a look at the docs for the dockmodal library you are using. There i found that you can specify a function to be called on the `open` event, defined within the options for the modal. Putting this change in fixes the issue, no need for css changes. Take a look at the updated code:

```js
var table = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
     dom:"<'row'<'#tblnoitfy'>><'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
     select: true,
     scrollY: 200,
     deferRender: true,
     //scrollY:     500,
     responsive: false,
     fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: true
     },
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": false,
      bAutoWidth: true,
      data: [],
      rowCallback: function (row, data) { },
});
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#mdl").dockmodal({
    open : function() {
      table.columns.adjust();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://uxmine.com/demo/dockmodal/assets/js/jquery.dockmodal.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://uxmine.com/demo/dockmodal/assets/css/jquery.dockmodal.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click ME!" />


<div style="display:none">
  <div id="mdl" class="panel-body">
    <input id="RegSrcsrcctl" type="text" />
    <input id="bt1" type="button" value="dummy search" />
    <table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th><b>File Number</b></th>
          <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
          <th><b>DOB</b></th>
          <th><b>Age</b></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see what you mean, below 550px the columns widths start to lose their property. is there any JS workaround?

Comment: The problem is that it happens only right after the initialization(loading), then it disappears

Comment: Ok i updated my response, this should fix the issue. Take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all the solutions. I just figured out a way to solve this on my own way.
First, add 100% width to datatable header.

```
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner{  width:100% !important; }
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table{  width:100% !important; }
```

Then after all the page contents have been loaded and shown, force datatable to redraw using "order".

```
$(div).show();
$('#datatable').DataTable().order([0, 'asc']).draw();
```

By this solution, I solved issues of header not fully across the table and misaligned. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting long time, I found the following solution works well on Chrome and Firefox. First, add the following CSS style:-

```
<style>
    .dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
        width:100% !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

In your javascript, you can add rows at anytime:-

```
table.rows.add(someJson);
table.draw();
```

where 'table' is a global variable pointing to the datatable:-

```
 table = $('#datatab').DataTable({
        ...
 });
```

In your html, add the width="100%" to the table:-

```
 <table id="datatab" class="..." width="100%">
       ...
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.
Got fixed after using the below code.

```
table.columns.adjust();
```

Answer (score 1):

These CSS solutions didn't work for me,
I checked the HTML and the header, footer and body had different tables where each table had its own specific width, I changed the width of all the tables in the container to 100% and it works well now

```css
.dataTables_scroll table {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another update,
Instead of forcing width to 100% upon initialization, I do it on the open event of the modal, yields more consistent outcome, I added more events to manage the modal resizing events.

Thanks to [Sasang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7852085/sasang)

```js
var table = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
     dom:"<'row'<'#tblnoitfy'>><'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
     select: true,
     scrollY: 200,
     deferRender: true,
     //scrollY:     500,
     responsive: false,
     fixedHeader: {
        header: true,
        footer: true
     },
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": false,
      bAutoWidth: true,
       data: [{"Filenum":15090248,"FullName":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"05 Dec 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":170418115,"FullName":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"05 Dec 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":170418116,"FullName":"Ahmad Morsi abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"05 Dec 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":170227111,"FullName":"asd dsf as a","DOB":"27 Feb 2017","Age":0},{"Filenum":15112775,"FullName":"marwam saleh moh saleem","DOB":"26 Nov 2015","Age":2},{"Filenum":15112777,"FullName":"marwam saleh moh saleem","DOB":"26 Nov 2015","Age":2},{"Filenum":15120996,"FullName":"marwam mohmmad  saleem","DOB":null,"Age":null},{"Filenum":160215104,"FullName":"marwam mohmmad abdul fattah Abu Maizer","DOB":"12 Mar 2016","Age":1},{"Filenum":15112270,"FullName":"mohammad j saleh raqaad","DOB":"22 Nov 2015","Age":2},{"Filenum":15112772,"FullName":"salem mohmmad john sarjes","DOB":"22 Oct 2011","Age":6}],
       "columns": [
       {
           "className": 'details-control',
           "width": "",
           "orderable": false,
           "data": null,
           "defaultContent": '<i data-toggle class="fa fa-plus-square-o text-primary h5 m-none" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>'
       },
       { "width": "20%", data: "Filenum" },
       { "width": "30%", data: "FullName" },
       { "width": "20%", data: "DOB" },
        { "width": "20%", data: "Age" }
            ],

            order: [[1, 'asc']]
      
      
});
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#mdl").dockmodal({
    open : function() {
      table.columns.adjust();
      $('#RegSrc').attr("style","width:100%")
    },
     popout: function () { table.columns.adjust(); },
        restore: function () { table.columns.adjust(); },
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://uxmine.com/demo/dockmodal/assets/js/jquery.dockmodal.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://uxmine.com/demo/dockmodal/assets/css/jquery.dockmodal.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click ME!" />


<div style="display:none">
  <div id="mdl" class="panel-body">
    <input id="RegSrcsrcctl" type="text" />
    <input id="bt1" type="button" value="dummy search" />
    <table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th><b>File Number</b></th>
          <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
          <th><b>DOB</b></th>
          <th><b>Age</b></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add CSS:

```
.dataTables_scrollHeadInner{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

And delayed columns.adjust() after loading data into the table

```
setTimeout(() => {resultsTable.columns.adjust()}, 50);
```

resultsTable is global variable DataTable